# Guarantee covariant return type with generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a class called `Point`, with a method `neighbors()` that returns an array of `Point`s:

```java
public class Point {
    public Point[] neighbors() { /* implementation not shown */ }
}
```

I have a subclass of `Point`, called `SpecialPoint` that overrides `neighbors()` to return an array of `SpecialPoint`s instead of `Point`s. I think this is called covariant return types.

```java
public class SpecialPoint extends Point {
    public SpecialPoint[] neighbors() { /* implementation not shown */ }
}
```

In a separate class, I want to make use of `Point` and `SpecialPoint` with generics

```java
public <P extends Point> P doStuff(P point) {
    P[] neighbors = point.neighbors();
    // more stuff here including return
}
```

This will not compile, because the compiler can only guarantee that `P` is some subclass of `Point`, but there is no guarantee that every subclass of `Point` will override `neighbors()` to return an array of itself as I happen to have done with `SpecialPoint`, so Java only knows that `P#neighbors()` returns `Point[]`, not `P[]`.

How do I guarantee that each subclass overrides `neighbors()` with a covariant return type so I can use it with generics?

Comment: Can P be an interface?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may use an interface:

```java
public interface Point<P extends Point<P>> {
    P[] neighbors();
}

public class SimplePoint implements Point<SimplePoint> {
    @Override
    public SimplePoint[] neighbors() { /* ... */ }
}

public class SpecialPoint implements Point<SpecialPoint> {
    @Override
    public SpecialPoint[] neighbors() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Then:

```java
public <P extends Point<P>> P doStuff(P point) {
    P[] neighbors = point.neighbors();
    /* ... */
}
```

---

If you still need to factorize code between the implementations, then better use an abstract class:

```java
public abstract class Point<P extends Point<P>> {
    public abstract P[] neighbors();
    public void commonMethod() { /* ... */ }
}

public class SimplePoint extends Point<SimplePoint> { /* ... */ }

public class SpecialPoint extends Point<SpecialPoint> { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Wow I never would have thought of this. My only problem is that I still want `SpecialPoint` to inherit from `SimplePoint` for other reasons. This way it won't compile because `P` in `Point` has to extend a `Point` also of `P`, but `SepcialPoint` extends `Point<SimplePoint>`. Anyway around this?

Comment: @JJW5432 What are those other reasons? An additional abstract class could suit your needs if the purpose is to factorize code.

Comment: Yes most of the other methods are the same between the classes, which is why I wanted inheritance. So there is AbstractPoint, and SimplePoint and SpecialPoint both inherit from it and implement Point<themsleves>?

Comment: @JJW5432 Well, the best would be to use an abstract class instead of an interface, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks this looks perfect! Just for my understanding, what is the significance of the generic in Point? As in if I had to explain in words what I meant by that class declaration, how would I explain P? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @JJW5432 Theoretically, it's any `Point` instance implementing subtype. Technically, it can actually be any `Point` subtype: it's the developer responsibility (i.e. you could write `class SimplePoint extends Point<SpecialPoint>`, it compiles while it doesn't make sense). If should be the case, calling the `<P extends Point<P>> P doStuff(P point)` method with such an instance won't compile anyway.

Comment: The bound in the declaration of `Point` is unused and unnecessary for the OP's purposes. `public interface Point<P>` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an `interface Point` solves your problem:

```
public class Test  
{

    public interface Point  {
        public Point[] neighbors();
    }

    public class SpecialPoint implements Point {
        public SpecialPoint[] neighbors() { return null; }
    }

    public class SpecialPoint2  implements Point {
        public SpecialPoint2[] neighbors() { return null; }
    }

    public Point doStuff(SpecialPoint point) {
        Point[] neighbors = point.neighbors();
        return neighbors[0];
    }

    public Point doStuff(SpecialPoint2 point) {
        Point[] neighbors = point.neighbors();
        return neighbors[0];
    }
}
```