# How to return a child class from a parent class in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have this one problem I simply can not put my head around. I am currently working on an Android project for school. I have a situation where I have a parent model class and several others extending from it. These models all have a similar storage mechanism (database). So method calls such as `findAll()` are more or the less the same for all the models. How can I implement this `findAll()` call in the parent class that will return an ArrayList of objects that are the caller subclass type?

Here is part my code so far:

**DEModel.java**

```
public abstract class DEModel {

    private static final String apiBasePath = "http://10.0.0.2:3000/api/";

    public static ArrayList<> getAll() {
        // 1. Make the API call
        // 2. Get the JSON result
        // 3. Extract objects from the JSON by calling the appropriate
        //    parser depending on the object type
        // 4. wrap the objects in an ArrayList and return them
    }
}
```

**Hotel.java**

```
public class Hotel extends DEModel {
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Hotel> hotels = Hotel.getAll();
    }
}
```

In the `DEModel.java` file, how can I specify a type that can be automatically figured out from the caller subclass? Can I even do this in a static context?

Thanks,
Tamrat

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676945 seems to match your problem. `getAll()` / `findAll()` is like the function `neighbours` presented over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **interface** the best poly polymorphism in java

- create empty interface of smth like DataObject
- make Hotel and others implements it
- now they may be considered as the same object DataObject

interface

```
public interface DataObject {
}
```

hotel

```
public class Hotel extends DEModel implements DataObject {
}
```

model

```
public abstract class DEModel {

    private static final String apiBasePath = "http://10.0.0.2:3000/api/";

    public static ArrayList<DataObject> getAll() {
        // 1. Make the API call
        // 2. Get the JSON result
        // 3. Extract objects from the JSON by calling the appropriate
        //    parser depending on the object type
        // 4. wrap the objects in an ArrayList and return them
    }
}
```

so you can use

```
ArrayList<DataObject> hotels = Hotel.getAll();
```

NOTE you will have to cast each object to Hotel to use it's methods and variables, smth like that

ArrayList hotels = Hotel.getAll();
for (DataObject obj : hotels) 
   Hotel h = (Hotel) obj
   h.getStarRating() // some method bound to Hotel and not to DataObject

you can also use

```
if (obj is instanceof Hotel)
    // do something
```

or

```
obj.getClass().getName()
```

but those methods output depends on how you created the `DataObject` in the first place in `getAll()`

Comment: Ahhh... Interesting. This indeed solves the problem pretty well. But is there a way to know which subclass made the call? And possibly get the class name?

Comment: @tamrat added some more examples and code, hope things are clearer   now... (let me know if not)

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working as expected now.